# Ao passar o mouse sobre as imagens, deve ser exibido o texto da propriedade "name", como acontece na primeira imagem, com o título Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const circles = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Twitter',
        image: 'img/twitter.jpg',
        color: '#aa2b31',
        size: 3
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Facebook',
        image: 'img/facebook.jpg',
        color: '#63e184',
        size: 1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Skype',
        image: 'img/skype.png',
        color: '#033d49',
        size: 2
    },
]

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const help = `
    <pre>
        <h1>Vianuvem Frontend Test</h1>
        Bem vindo ao teste de frontend da Vianuvem!
        Esse é um teste simples, elaborado para conhecermos um pouco mais sobre como você trabalha.
        Nessa primeira etapa, você precisa consumir o serviço abaixo e criar uma tela conforme a imagem a seguir:

        <h2>Imagem da tela vista em computador</h2>
        <img src="img/screen_1.png"/>
        <h2>Imagem da tela vista em celular</h2>
        <img src="img/screen_2.png"/>
        GET /circles
        UTILIZAÇÃO:
        Obtém todos os "círculos" disponíveis para a criação da tela
        <ol>
            <h2>Regras</h2>
            <li>O projeto deverá ser desenvolvido com Javascript puro e / ou jQuery</li>
            <li>Projetos responsivos tendem a ser mais bem avaliados</li>
            <li>A API já está criada, e nenhuma alteração nela é permitida</li>
            <li>Ao passar o mouse sobre as imagens, deve ser exibido o texto da propriedade "name", como acontece na primeira imagem, com o título Twitter</li>
            <li>Todo o desenvolvimento será avaliado</li>
            <li>Após o termino, entregue o projeto via Github ou arquivo .zip</li>
        </ol>
    </pre>
`
    res.send(help)
})

app.get('/circles', (req, res) => {
    res.send(circles)
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3001')
})[vianuvem-frontend-test-master][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar um texto que será exibido ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem você utiliza o atributo ALT. Exemplo:

```
<img src="img/screen_1.png" alt="Tela 1"/>
```

Caso você queira adicionar imagens na página utilizando o array circles, você pode usar este exemplo feito em javascript como referência:

```js
var imgs = "";
for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', circles[i]->image);
  img.setAttribute('alt', circles[i]->name);
  imgs += img.outerHTML;
}

var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.innerHTML = imgs;
```

No caso, "container" seria o ID de algum elemento da página, como uma div, por exemplo